# Aligning images with different dimensions in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with a fixed width and 3 images with different widths and heights. The goal I struggle to achieve:

1. Images are displayed in a row
2. Row of images is filling the wrapping container in summary width
3. Height of a row is calculated automatically
4. Height and width of each image is scaled preserving its ratio
5. Images in a row have fixed margin in between, but not on the left nor right sides.

The illustration of desired result:
 [image]

How to perform this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You can set image width with percentage values, removing fixed margins, like `width: calc(25% - 20px);`

Comment: Jeroen Heier, I've tried 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
which works only if images are of same height.

Comment: marcelo2605, that's not quite what will help to achieve the result displayed on the image I've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a common fixed height and auto width for the images and use flex with `justify-content: space-between` on the container

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container>img {
  height: 120px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/fa0">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/160x300/0fa">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/500x180/f0a">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, it definitely works: https://jsfiddle.net/c7gj31d6/
It seems that I've formulated my question in a wrong way then, because the real problem is to use it with Divi theme for Wordpress. Images there are wrapped in several containers each with its own styles, and I can't make this work there.

Comment: Well, there are probably lots of other styles applied by Divi and WP itself which might have extremely specific CSS selectors. You can try to add `!important` to all settings above, but there might be some other parameters which you'd also have to "neutralize" by adding their default settings including `!important`. But in general it's better to look at what the theme's styles do which you don't want and change that into the described direction.

Answer (score 0):

add this style for your container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

and that doesn't matter what are your images' widths and heights

Comment: Hello, thanks for an answer. I already tried this method, it works as intended only if all images are of the same height.